# Bounded by exponential implies uniformly integrable?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Suppose I have a sequence of r.v.'s $\left\{X_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. I have shown that $\mathbb{P}\left( \left|X_n\right| > a\right) < C_1e^{-C_2 a}$ for all $n$. From here, I can show that $\lim_{a\to\infty} \sup_n \mathbb{P}\left(\left| X_n\right| > a\right) = 0$. My question is, does this imply that $X_n$'s are uniformly integrable?

I know that if $\sup_n \left|X_n\right| < Y$ and $\mathbb{E}\left[Y\right] < \infty$, then $X_n$'s are uniformly integrable. But do I have to construct an explicit random variable here? This [notes](http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/stochastic-I/stochastic-I-UI-light.pdf) says that

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have necessarily to construct such a random variable $Y$ (it is a sufficient condition, but not a necessary one). One possible approach to prove the uniform integrability is the following:

For any non-negative random variable $Z$ it holds that

$$\mathbb{E}(Z) = \int_0^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(Z > r) \, dr.$$

Applying this to $Z := 1_{|X_n|>a} |X_n|$ (for fixed $n$ and $a$) we find

$$\begin{align*} \int_{|X_n|>a} |X_n| \, d\mathbb{P} &= \int_0^a \mathbb{P}(|X_n|>a) \, dr +\int_a^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(|X_n|>r) \, dr  \\ &\leq C_1a e^{-C_2a } + C_1 \int_a^{\infty} e^{-C_2r} \, dr. \end{align*}$$

Thus,

$$\sup_{n \geq 1} \int_{|X_n|>a} |X_n| \, d\mathbb{P} \leq C_1a e^{-C_2a } + C_1 \int_a^{\infty} e^{-C_2 r} \, dr \xrightarrow[]{a \to \infty} 0$$

which shows that $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is uniformly integrable.

Comment: Why is the first equation true?

Comment: @iseliget It's a direct consequence of Tonelli's theorem; see the first part of this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1201583/36150

Comment: I see. So we are implicitly introducing some product measure/space here? Say if $Z$ is on $\Omega$, then we are implicitly working with $\Omega \times \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @iseliget Well, no. For the proof of the identity we need to construct a product space, but not in order to apply the identity.

Comment: I see. Also it's not clear to me why $\int_0^a \mathbb{P}\left( 1_{|X_n| > a} |X_n| >r\right) \,dr = 0$ (which assume makes the first equality on the second line work)?

Comment: @iseliget Sorry, I forgot about the first term... should be fine now.